Spring embedded Tomcat connection much slower than external Tomcat datasource
I am trying to configure connection from Spring to a MySQL database using Eclipselink JPA. I managed to run the application using the embedded Tomcat server with the next configuration file:
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class EclipseLinkJpaConfigurationTomcatEmbed {
   
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try{            
            final Properties pool = new Properties();
            pool.put("driverClassName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            pool.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useSSL=false");
            pool.put("username", "user");
            pool.put("password", "pass");
            return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory().createDataSource(pool);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "myapp" });
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false"); 
        properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "INFO");
        properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "none");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}


I have been doing many tests and for some reason when running the application using tomcat ebedded container performance is much slower than using the external Tomcat. For example, an intensive function that reads many entities takes 800ms with the second configuration and 17s with the second one. I have been trying different configurations with the same result.
What I have tried:

Using exactly the same Tomcat version embedded and external.
Using exactly the same configuration for embedded and external tomcat.
Disabling "reloadable" in EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer didn't work either.

Edit note: there is something wierd I noticed.  Embededed tomcat uses 20 connections with database but external tomcat uses just 10. So there must be some configuration "somewhere" that could explain the performance difference.
I triggered a fake exception in the middle of a transaction:
1. Embedded tomcat
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nombre' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:909) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:981) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:569) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2048) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:311) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:280) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:266) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:436) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:193) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:209) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:514) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:86) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:97) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:326) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:61) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:913) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:812) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:109) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:86) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3025) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1841) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1823) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1773) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:248) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:147) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4335) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1515) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1605) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:287) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1242) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:137) ~[eclipselink-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:794) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:676) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:426) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at zerog.uuu.TestController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.test(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at zerog.config.HtmlCompressorFilter.doFilter(HtmlCompressorFilter.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at zerog.config.PlayerSessionFilter.doFilter(PlayerSessionFilter.java:51) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2. External tomcat
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nombre' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO galaxias (id, centro_sx, centro_sy, nombre, radio, tipo, ultimo_despliegue_sx, ultimo_despliegue_sy, partida) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [9 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(zerog.core.espacio.galaxia.Galaxia@44e)
2024-06-07T22:52:31.965+02:00 ERROR 19396 --- [zerogs] [p-nio-80-exec-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/test/test] due to exception [Could not commit JPA transaction]

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:794) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:676) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:426) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at zerog.uuu.TestController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.test(<generated>) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:619) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:716) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at zerog.config.HtmlCompressorFilter.doFilter(HtmlCompressorFilter.java:32) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at zerog.config.PlayerSessionFilter.doFilter(PlayerSessionFilter.java:51) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124) ~[na:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99) ~[na:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) ~[na:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[na:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:338) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[tomcat-util.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) ~[tomcat-util.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:11.0.0-M16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nombre' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO galaxias (id, centro_sx, centro_sy, nombre, radio, tipo, ultimo_despliegue_sx, ultimo_despliegue_sy, partida) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [9 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(zerog.core.espacio.galaxia.Galaxia@44e)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[na:6.1.6]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException: 
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nombre' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO galaxias (id, centro_sx, centro_sy, nombre, radio, tipo, ultimo_despliegue_sx, ultimo_despliegue_sy, partida) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [9 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(zerog.core.espacio.galaxia.Galaxia@44e)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:334) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:919) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:981) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:569) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2048) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:311) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:280) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:266) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:436) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:193) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:209) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:514) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:86) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:97) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:326) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:61) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:913) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:812) ~[na:4.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:109) ~[na:4.0.2]
        

Solucion: As Dudi By pointed out, embedded tomcat wasnt using Hikari because it wasnt correctly configured. The next configuration worked for me and balanced performance.
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useSSL=false");
        config.setUsername("xxx");
        config.setPassword("vvv");

        // Specific HikariCP configuration
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        config.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        config.setIdleTimeout(600000);
        config.setMaxLifetime(1800000);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }


testOnBorrow might be expensive for performance. Also, how many requests were sent? A single request might not be a good measure.

I have been testing with single requests, the difference is huge betwen both configurations. testOnBorrow and therest o properties are exactly the same that you can find in the datasource defined in server.xml in the other 1st configuration

initialization has a cost, try several requests. Also check how many connections are opened in both cases, here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136693/how-to-check-hikaricp-connection-pooling-is-working-or-not-in-java

I have been trying with exactly the same configuration. Problems seems to be related to tomcat embed default internal configuration. The number of threads to the database is 20 with external tomcat, 10 with embed tomcat, but in any case, app speeds up once the JPA eclipselink caché is loaded, reducining times, but even then, speed is much slower with tomcat embed

could be different libraries implementing the JPA and JDBC. Suggesting to debug 2 environments and put breakpoint on database query. Inspect the stack trace to analyze the relevant packages and versions involved.

@DudiBoy I ran two instances at the same time, using FINEST log but I cannt find any diferences between them.  Both instances connect using MSQL Connector/J. What kind of packages or versions you mean?

Please post in the question  full stack traces (each from respected environment) of the a breakpoint in the repository level save/flush. There could be implicit second level cache in the stack trace. Packages like hibernate/ehcache etc... Second level cache stores database data in memory.

@DudiBoy I just posted Eclipselink full stack of both applications. There is no difference between them. Eclipselink has shared cache active by default. You know it after doing a second request of same objects. Comparing a larger algorithm external tomcat takes 3000ms -> 1000ms (second request) and embedded 17s -> 10s (second request), for the same operations.

please post in the question. stack trace from both environments of a debug breakpoint or generate an exception (with erroneous call). you already posted detailed log file with timestamps. we need stack trace.

@DudiBoy sorry, I didnt understand what you meant. Excellent idea, I didnt think on triggering an Exception. I updated the question, is it what you requested?

almost, indeed you posted both stack traces. They are identical. But we need stack trace at the exception from a JPA repository mananger . Try saving a record with duplicate id, or create a record with illegal value (too long string, or number into string, string into num etc).
